# how to make json in java

Tags: android, json

I am having problem putting jsonObject(s) in jsonArray.

here is JSON format:

```
     {
       "op": "add",
       "array": 
           [
            {
             "field": "fld",
             "value": "20"
            },
            {
             "field": "fldu",
             "value": "z"
            }
           ]
    }
```

I am trying with this code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonObj .put("operation", "add");
jsonObj .put("array",jsonArray.put( jsonObj.put("field", "fld_name")));
```

but it gives an error. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: your not providing index of array.

Comment: Plus your question should be more like putting jsonObject in Json array and then in Jsonarray in Json Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("operation","add");

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject fields1 = new JSONObject();
fields1.put("field","fld");
fields1.put("value","20");
JSONObject fields2 = new JSONObject();
fields2.put("field","fldu");
fields2.put("value","z");

array.put(fields1);
array.put(fields2);

json.put("array",array);
```

Comment: yes it is that i want. so it means i have to create jsonObect for fields like fields3 and fields4 as i need. thankx man.

Comment: np my friend :) great to ear that my solution is good for you :)

Comment: can u please tell how can i make two dimensional jsonarray ??

Comment: like this at [0] = "operation","add" 
at [1] = ("field","fld") ,("value","20")
at [2] = ("field","fldu"), ("value","z")